What is the legal situation if one is owed money but no longer have access to the bank account associated with the account?
There is a situation presented in The Guardian
Consumer champions that must be fairly common:

In November last year, I unexpectedly rediscovered an unused national lottery app on my mobile phone with a balance of £2.50.
I bought a Lotto ticket and won £106. But when I tried to withdraw the money, I couldn’t, as my bank card attached to the account was no longer in use, and you can only change your card if your balance is zero.

This is explained:

for players’ safety and security, it seeks to prevent funds being deposited into a national lottery account from one debit card and withdrawn on another.

What is the legal situation here?  Can a company refuse to pay money it owes in such a situation?  Can such a situation be legally created by contract?  If one took such a case to the small claims court is one likely to prevail?  Is it relevant that this is gambling winnings?
